# Is my proof that $\ell^p$ is Banach correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I would like to show that $\ell^p$, for $p \in [1, \infty)$ is Banach, using the following fact: Given a normed linear space $X$, $X$ is Banach if and only if absolute convergence in $X$ implies conditional convergence in $X$. Here's what I've done:

> Let $\{ x_n \}$ be a sequence in $\ell^p$ with the property that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\| x_n \|_{\ell^p} < \infty$. I must show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n := \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ is an element of $\ell_p$. But we have the chain of inequalities

\begin{align}
& \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \Bigl| \Bigl( \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n \Bigr)(\ell) \Bigr|^p = 
\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \Bigl| \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n (\ell) \Bigr|^p \leq
\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \Bigl| x_n (\ell) \Bigr|^p \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigl| x_n (\ell) \Bigr|^p = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \Bigl| x_n (\ell) \Bigr|^p =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\|^p_{\ell^p} < \infty,
\end{align}

> where the final inequality holds because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\| x_n \|_{\ell^p} < \infty$. Thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n \in \ell^p$, as desired.

Is my proof correct? If not, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The only inequality in your chain is false. Compare $(1+1)^p$ and $1^p+1^p$, where $p>1$.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat oh shoot, you're right, thanks for replying. That was pretty bad, haha. Do you think there's any way to save this argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Minkowski's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) to repair the proof. First of all, note that for every $k$ the numeric series $\sum_n x_n(k)$ converges absolutely; let $x(k)$ denote its sum. The goal is to prove that $x\in \ell^p$. By Minkowski's inequality,  the partial sums   $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n$ are uniformly bounded in $\ell^p$: 
$$
\|S_N\|_p=\left\| \sum_{n=1}^Nx_n \right\|_p\le \sum_{n=1}^N\|x_n\|_p \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\|_p $$
Fatou's lemma implies
$$
\sum_k |x(k)|^p \le \liminf_{N\to\infty} \sum_k |S_N(k)|^p  
\tag1$$
which is finite by the above.

(Fatou's lemma is being applied to the measure space $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure. If you don't like this, prove (1) directly by considering partial sums over $1\le k\le K$.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go over this and make sure I understand everything. It's mostly the application of the Fatou's lemma I want to wrap my head around; I haven't seen it in the general measure space setting before.

Comment: I'm just wondering what I am misunderstanding: if we start with an absolutely convergent series in $\ell_p$, i.e. $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}||x_n||_p< \infty$, and then for each $k$, we know that the element-wise sum of each $k$ converges to say $\hat{x_k}$. So if we set $\hat{x}$ to be the sequence of these $\hat{x_k}'s$ - why can we not immediately conclude that $\hat{x} = ||\sum^{\infty}x_n||_p < \infty$ (by the triangle inequality)? I must be missing something...

Comment: @TerrenceJ The triangle inequality $\|a+b\|\le \|a\|+\|b\|$ is about the sum of two terms. One can generalize it to __finitely many__ in a straightforward way.  Here we have an infinite series which is not known to converge in $\ell^p$ norm.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I understand where I am going wrong now.

Comment: @404 And just to clarify, you would place the RHS of $(1)$ to be smaller or equals to the LHS of the above string of inequalities right? I tried a few small examples for myself, and that seems to be true? Thanks!